# Set up a NTP server which can be queried globally

Tags: networking, ntp

I want to set up a server (hosted on aws/or a running system in some part of the world) as an NTP server that can be queried globally.

Currently, I have modified the ntp.conf file on the node to be made the server as server . But the problem is, on using an NTP client if I try to query time from this server, or rather on using sudo ntpdate  it says no suitable server found.

However, if I replicate the same on my local network (the server, as well as the querying node, are all on the local network) then this works perfectly fine.

I think the problem might lie in the ntp.conf file. Do I need to put some specific restrict lines for this to work publicly as well? And no I cannot list the server on public ntp pages. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Have you checked any external firewalls etc? Or could this be a loopback issue within your network?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This was a port issue. I was testing it on aws and had to manually open the related udp ports.